# ORM design w/o Hibernate Help required

Tags: jdbc, orm

I'm working on my first pet project and  my goal is to parse local job sites and save relevant positions to RDB. So, I'wont touch Hibernate until I create JDBC version. My database model is fairly simple: first (main) table 'Positions' with its ID as a foreign key for the second one called 'Skills'. They're relate as "one to many".

My main question is about constructing apropriate design of the code architecture. Due to lack of expirience in patterns I could miss some conceptions.
My thoughts:
1) Variant to build one class for vacancies and one for skillset, than we map both objects into database;
2) Variant with aggregation: creating enum set of skills inside one class "Vacancy" than map it on two tables;
3)..?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have entity Position and Skill. The relationship between them should be IMO many-to-many, because one skill may be needed for different positions and one position may require several skills. It means, that on database level you will require 3 tables: positions, skills and position_skill (which will serve as intermediate table between first two).

On code level you will need entity classes Position and Skill bound by a "has-a" relationship: class Position has a collection of skill inside.

Than you will need repository (DAO) classes, which will be responsible for retrieving entities from database. When using plain JDBC you should implement methods for CRUD (create, read, update, delete) operations for both entities. Mapping from ResultSet to entity class can be implemented either in repository classes or in separate mapper classes (takes ResultSet as parameter returns Position or Skill instance). Challenging task (when not using frameworks) would be implementing pagination with filtering and sorting support.

Than you'll need service classes, which should implement the business logic, when you decide to add it.

If you're implementing a web application or REST-/Web- services, you'll need controller classes, which will handle HTTP requests.

The chain of events looks as follows: client calls controller, controller invokes service, service calls repository, which retrieves data from database. This layered structure is used in many applications and can be implemented in plain java using singletons or with usage of spring / java ee frameworks.

Good luck.